# Dynamic calling of JBehave steps from inside Java

Tags: java, jbehave

In Java I have a `String` object that has the text that I wish to be matched and executed by `JBehave` as a step. How can this be done? Can it be done?

What I am really trying to do is to have a wrapper `JBehave` step that instruments another arbitrary `JBehave` step. It does a few things before and after calling on the "inner" step.

So lets say that I already have the following

```
When I say Hello World
```

and

```
@When("I say $text")
public void iSay(final String text)
{
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

I want to be able to do the following :

```
When I repeat 4 times I say Hello World
```

it will call :

```
@When("I repeat $count times $subStepString")
public void repeat(final int repeatCount, final String subStepString)
{
    // prep code here
    for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++)
    {
        howDoIdoThisBitHere(subStepString);
    }
    // post process code here
}
```

The part that says howDoIdoThisBitHere(...) should end up having JBehave match the value of `subStepString` as if it was encountered in the case above. This way I can use this method to call other arbitrary things.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the segment of code you're referring to

Comment: Expanded with some example (psuedo-)code to help illustrate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a great idea since the step classes shouldn't have any dependency on the core configuration (StepMatchers, Runners etc.), but is this solution kind of what you're looking for?

```
@When("I repeat $count times $subStepString")
public void repeat(final int repeatCount, final String subStepString)
{
    // prep code here
    for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++)
    {
        StoryParser sp = configuration().storyParser();
        Story s = sp.parseStory(subStepString);
        StoryRunner e = configuredEmbedder().storyRunner();
        e.run(configuration(), configuredEmbedder().candidateSteps(), s);
    }
}
```